# How to associate a softphone with a phone url

Tags: voip, firefox, crm, softphone

I'm trying to get click to call to work using Qutecom for a softphone and a Greesemonkey script to turn phone numbers into clickable urls. Whenever I click on the phone number link I get an error message saying the following:

Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (tel) isn't associated with any program.

How would I go about associating Qutecom, or any other softphone, with that link? The Greasemonkey scribt can be found at the link below:

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/56262

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MozillaZine has a page describing how to add new protocol handlers [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol). On Windows, it looks like it just amounts to a couple minor modifications to the registry. Open Notepad and paste in the following:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel]
@="URL:Custom Telephone Protocol for Qutecom VoIP Softphone"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\qutecom\\qutecom.exe\" -c \"call\\%1\""
```

Save the file with a `.reg` extension (e.g. `tel-url.reg`). You will need to actually type out the `.reg`, otherwise Notepad will assume `.txt`. You can then import these settings into the PC's registry by double-clicking on the file you just created. I don't know if Firefox reads these registry keys directly, or if it depends on Explorer for that, so it's possible that you may need to restart Windows for the change to take effect.

The process for Mac and Linux is different, and involves setting the following preferences in Firefox itself:

- `network.protocol-handler.external.foo`
- `network.protocol-handler.app.foo`

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not having any success. I try to launch for the command line with; "c:\program files\qutecom\qutecom.exe" -c call\19999999999, but it only opens the app. No number is dialed. QuteCom documentation says that the command to dial is qutecom -c call\123456. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're on Windows, the `command` registry entry probably needs to look like `@="\"C:\\Program Files\\qutecom\\qutecom.exe\" \"-c\" \"call\\%1\""`.

Comment: I apologize, but I'm new to this. When I enter it in like that into the command line, I get an error saying "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect". I set up everything through regedit. It seems like you might have done it through the command line. Maybe that is where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the additional information you provided. I hope my answer is clearer now.

Comment: I got it working for a few calls, but then it stopped. Now, it seems like the browser is passing "tell:" along with the number. I tried tel:1111111111 in Firefox and Explorer and each has the same problem. The error message it gives is user/number not found tel:+1111111111. If I issue the command from the command line, QuteCom dials the number just fine. Thanks for your help. It looks like it will be another day of fiddling for me.

Comment: I don't know enough about how Firefox does these things to say for certain, but maybe it depends on the protocol including the slashes, e.g. `tel://1111111111`.

Comment: It sems to be the % that is causing the problem. If I take the %1 off and replace it with a +, it passes 001, without the tell:+. I've tried a bunch of different combinations, but there doesn't seem to be a way to di it without the %.

Comment: The `%1` is supposed to expand to the first "argument" in the URL, which should be the part after the colon.

Comment: Can the % be replaced by anything?

Comment: I did a quick test, and the problem appears to be that the full URL is passed to the Qutecom command line, including the `tel:` part. This means that unless Qutecom can be instructed to handle the number in URL form, you'll probably need to write a wrapper script or program that strips off the `tel:` part, and the runs Qutecom with the appropriate arguments for you. I'm not a Windows developer, though, so I'm not the best person to advise on how to proceed from here.

Comment: I wrote a batch file to do that. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Glad I could help.